# How to upload a temporary file on S3

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a way to upload a file to S3 and set the autodeletion in 2 hours, for example?

I really don't want to write a cleanup program

Comment: There is no such capability provided by Amazon S3. You would need to write some code to perform this auto-cleanup. However, you could use an Amazon S3 Lifecycle policy, but this applies to a whole bucket or directory, not just a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Now AWS has introduced an option to expire a file automatically. You can set the policy of the bucket to expire files after a certain period of time or move to a cheaper storage from s3 bucket.

You can find more information from this [AWS Documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html)

[image]

Comment: Please note that this would apply to the whole bucket, or a selected path within the bucket. It is not specific to a given object.